# $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}}\text { does not exist }$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I make this rigorous?

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{\overline{z}}\text { does not exist }$$

Proof:

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{x+iy}{x-iy} \text{ taking } y\ne 0, x\to 0 \implies \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y)}\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}=\frac{iy}{-iy}=-1$$
Take $y\to 0$, $x\ne 0$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x,0)}\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}=\frac{x}{x}=1$$

Since these limits aren't equal, this limit does not exist.

Is this rigorous?

---

Secondary:

$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{x+iy}{x-iy}$$

Set $x=0$ and approach from $y\to 0$:

$$\lim_{y\to0} \frac{iy}{-iy}=-1$$

Set $y=0$ and approach from $x\to 0$
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x}{x}=1$$

Since the limit's value is not independent of direction, the limit does not exist.

Comment: No, what you actually want to do is to compute the limit of $f(x,0)$ when $x\to0$ and the limit of $f(0,y)$ when $y\to0$, and to compare them.

Comment: @Did Apologies, I see. Thank you. Would such a problem normally be approached via $\epsilon-\delta$ or the version you suggest

Comment: Nope. Your question includes things like $(x,y)\to(0,y)$, which are unrelated.

Comment: You didn't complete it. You never let the other component approach zero.

Comment: @Did is this better?

Comment: @MPW is this better?

Comment: Indeed, your "Secondary" paragraph follows the suggestion in my first comment and yields a more correct solution, modulo the strange formulation "approach from [something]$\to0$". (Note to users: My second comment answers a now deleted version of the OP's first comment.)

Comment: @Did Now deleted within 5 seconds of making it admittedly. What is wrong with the $(\text{answer}/(\text{approach from [something]})\text{answer})$ quotient group?

Comment: ?? Two points: 1. My first comment indicates precisely the way to a fully rigorous proof, just folllow it completely instead of at 50%. 2. The "quotient group" question in your last comment is squarely impossible to understand.

Comment: in polar coordinates, $\dfrac z{\bar z} = e^{2i\theta}.$  pick any $\theta$ you want, and approach zero along the the line $y = \tan \theta,$ the limit is $e^{2i\theta}.$ does not have a unique vale.

Comment: @Did Sorry I was making a joke out of your modulo strange formulation thing, by explicitly showing the relevant quotient group

Comment: That's essentially correct now. Wording is a bit nonstandard, but the proof is there. For clarity, you could say something like "First let $z\to 0$ along the positive vertical axis, which gives $\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(0+it)=(0+it)/(0-it)=\cdots$" and so on. But I would give your answer full credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x+iy}{x-iy} $$
Using polar coordinates, we have
$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{r\cos\phi+ir\sin\phi}{r\cos\phi-ir\sin\phi} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{\cos\phi+i\sin\phi}{\cos\phi-i\sin\phi} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{e^{i\phi}}{e^{-i\phi}}= e^{2i\phi} $$
This limit is clearly dependent on $\phi$. Therefore,
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}\;\text{does not exist} $$